# Ubuntu 14 Android Studio 3 xrdp /dev/kvm permission denied

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, android-studio, xrdp

I'm running an Ubuntu Server VPS with 4 dedicated cores and 4GB or ram

```
lsb_release -a
```

says I'm running

```
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
Codename: trusty
```

I've installed Android Studio 3.0.1
I more or less followed this [Tutorial](https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/10/23/ubuntu-16-04-install-android-studio-2-2/) just got the latest version. the install when smoothly.

I then installed xrdp and xfce4, and I'm not having any issues with the remote connections

I launch android studio with the following command from an elevated terminal window in rdp

```
sudo ~/bin/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

the command outputs

```
Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string: ''
```

but android studio runs fine and allows my to make projects and code so I tried compiling the hello world app and running it in a ADV after creating an android virtual phone and trying to run I get the following error

```
KVM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm device: permission denied
Grant current user access to /dev/kvm
```

I've run

```
usermod -aG kvm *username*
usermod -aG libvirtd *username"
adduser *username* kvm
adduser *username* libvirtd
adduser *username* xrdp
chmod +x /dev/kvm
chown *username* /dev/kvm
chmod -R 777  /dev/kvm
```

I rebooted the VPS after each of the commands and I still get the KVM permission denied error

When I run

```
  sudo kvm-ok
    INFO: /dev/kvm exists
    KVM acceleration can be used
```

However if I just run

```
kvm-ok 
bash: kvm-ok: command not found
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and have only found stuff telling me to add the user to kvm and/or libvirtd groups any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Looking into this some more

```
 cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'name'| uniq 
 model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
```

so I ran

```
sudo modprobe kvm-intel
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file()
could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0/modules.builtin.bin'
```

this lead to me trying

```
depmod -a
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.13.0/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.13.0/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

here is the out put of `ls -al /lib/modules/3.13.0/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 12 01:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 12288 Dec 11 18:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    45 Dec 12 01:08 modules.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Dec 12 01:08 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Dec 12 01:08 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Dec 12 01:08 modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Dec 12 01:08 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    52 Dec 12 01:08 modules.devname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   131 Dec 12 01:08 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    49 Dec 12 01:08 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Dec 12 01:08 modules.symbols.bin
```

so I was thinking there was an error with my linux image, but

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

not sure what to fix but I think I'm getting closer to figuring out the issue at least

Comment: I ultimately found that kvm was disabled on my azzo managed vps. the VPS was destroyed nearly a year ago, so I can't try any answers.

Comment: See also my answer to a similar question on StackOverflow: [Android Studio: /dev/kvm device permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61984745/427158)

Answer (score 43):

I had this mistake with Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 when I run emulator. You can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/5595925). To add the user username to the kvm group, you could use:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

In my case it worked, albeit with a re-login required after whole process.

Comment: my question already says this was attempted, I ultimately found that kvm was disabled on my azzo managed vps.

Comment: Solved the problem for me. However, Re-Login is necessary after these commands.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading to 18.04 and your answer solved it ! Can someone explain what is qemu-kvm and why it is now required ?

Comment: @Fabich KVM = Kernel-Based Virtual Machine. It allows for different architecture emulation. I'm also trying to get android studio running on 18.04 sadly nothing has resolved this for me.

Comment: it didn't change anything, android studio still shows error message with kvm

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, try install: sudo apt install cpu-checker

Comment: Combination of this answer and some commands from below answers helped me get this working in 2019!

Answer (score 30):

it is too late answer , may be help another users .

1.i tried :`sudo setfacl -m u:UserName:rwx /dev/kvm`  . and it works .

2.in the android studio you need to change : tools> avd manager >(chose the pen to edit your device and change 'graphics' from automatic  to software ) to avoid emulator drawable  error

Comment: Thanks. Step 1 worked for me. Not sure what step 2 is for but seems unrelated to the main problem and I didn't need to do it.

Comment: Worked for me as well +1 from my side.

Answer (score 21):

This works for Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Open a terminal and type the following

   - `sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rwx /dev/kvm`
2. Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure virtualization is enabled in BIOS.
Add your username to the group properties:

```
sudo chown :$USER /dev/kvm
```

let the user access/write to the device /dev/kvm:

```
sudo chmod g+rw /dev/kvm
```

that's it!

Comment: was VPS with no access to bios, tried first command (see question) and I did `chmod -R 777 /dev/kvm` so I feel like that would have worked, regardless VPS no longer exists and I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Update VT setting from Bios

1. Power on the system and press[delete] key to enter BIOS [EZ Mode]
2. Press [F7] key to enter BIOS [Advance Mode] as below picture：
   (If press [delete] key to enter [Advanced Mode] directly and then no need to press [F7] key any more)
3. Select  [Advanced] page and click [CPU Configuration] item
4. Select [Intel(VMX) Virtualization Technology] item and set to [Enabled]
5. Press [F10] key and click [OK] ,the system will auto reboot

https://www.asus.com/in/support/FAQ/1045141/#A