# Android Studio not recognising KVM on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization, android-studio

KVM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm device: permission denied.

Grant current user access to /dev/kvm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14 Android Studio 3 xrdp /dev/kvm permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985142/ubuntu-14-android-studio-3-xrdp-dev-kvm-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

I had this mistake with Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 when I run the emulator. You can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/5595925). To add the user username to the kvm group, you could use:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

In my case it worked, albeit with a re-login required after the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

first of all paste in your terminal

```
kvm-ok
```

if you got dev/kvm not exist,
KVM acceleration can not be used ,
your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.